# Android on Netbeans 6.9.1: Package name not valid

Tags: android, netbeans-6.9

I am new to Android Development. Actually, I haven't started yet because I always get the error: "Package name not valid" when trying to create a new Project in Netbeans 6.9.1. I've installed Android SDK (path is set in NB) and Platforms are available. Does anyone know what I've done wrong or how I could solve my problem. I want to start soon.

Sincerely

Comment: Can you show the package name in question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For creating a package use a dot, not a space, example:
`android.bug` not `android bug`

Answer (score 2):

It has to be in reverse DNS format (e.g. com.example). More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-DNS).

Comment: It can be, but does not need to be. 'foo' is a valid package name.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a pretty old topic, I'll add one more reason one why someone can get an invalid package name.

The package name cannot include a Java language keyword such as int, long, interface, etc. For example, "com.myDomain.myApp.interface" would not be a valid package name. However, "com.myDomain.myApp.interface_" is a valid package name.